# Repeated eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvalue for sum of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I read a lecture note and there is a sentence which makes some confusion:

Let $M$ be a real matrix. If $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i+1}$ be repeated eigenvalues then $\psi_i + \psi_{i+1}$ will be an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

Based on the formula $M\psi_i=\lambda_i \psi_i$, $\psi_i + \psi_{i+1}$ should be the eigenvector with eigenvalue $2\lambda_i$? Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$M(\psi_i+\psi_{i+1})=M\psi_i+M\psi_{i+1}=\lambda_i\psi_i+\lambda_i\psi_{i+1}=\lambda_i(\psi_i+\psi_{i+1})$$

Hence the eigenvalue remains to be $\lambda_i$.

Remark:

A relevant keyword would be **Eigenspace**.